# Why is dynamic prop passed for styling not being applied to my child component?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to pass an opacity prop `op`. Here I'm calculating it in the parent component then I passing it:

```
cardOpacity = Date.now() < (entry.lastCompleted / 1000000 + 43200000)? 0.5 : 1
return (
  <ChallengeCarousel
    key={index}
    title={entry.title}
    op={cardOpacity}
    onOpenWebsite={funcOpenWebsite}
  />
);
```

In the child, I tried a couple different ways of adding it, by putting it in an object using `StyleSheet.create()` and putting that into the styles array. I also tried dropping it in as an object in the styles array.

```
render () {
  const {op} = this.props;
  const opacityStyles = StyleSheet.create({
    card: {
      opacity: op
    }
  })
return (
  <TouchableHighlight
    activeOpacity={ 0.5 }
    underlayColor={ '#fff' }
    style={ styles.slideInnerContainer }
    onPress={ () => { this.goChallengeActivityDetail() }}
  >
    <View style={ styles.contentContainer }>
        <View style={[opacityStyles.card, styles.centerContainer, {opacity: op}]}> 
          <Text numberOfLines={2} style={ styles.description }>{ subtitle } </Text>
        </View>
    </View>
  </TouchableHighlight>
);
```

Another clue is that when I change things in the parent I see the effect but when I make a change directly into the component, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: can you print the value of the opacity in the child component and see if it's changing?

Comment: thanks @packability i was checking it in the parent but not in the child. Turns out there are 2 components with exactly the same name! -1 for terrible coding practices.